# Java java.lang.ArithmeticException finding multiples of a number

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to find the multiples of the numbers being inputted, but every time the user enters 0 i get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Yes i know that you cant divide by zero but there has to be a way to make this work.

This is suppose to still work even with the zero being inputted.

```
 public static int prob1Rec(int num1, int num2) {

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++) {
            if ((i % num1 == 0) || (i % num2 == 0)) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Note: If one of the numbers is zero, i still want to add up the multiples of the other number.

Comment: Why do you think it should work? Why don't you check for 0 and do something else?

Comment: Put the `for` loop into an `if`: `if (num1 != 0 && num2 != 0) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `if` to

```
if ((num1 != 0 && i % num1 == 0) || (num2 != 0 && i % num2 == 0)) {
```

Comment: i did this and everything else mentioned here by everyone else but the professor is saying the result should be 57918, but i think i am going to vote your answer as the answer because i believe the professor did a mistake or something.

Comment: What input does the professor think will give you an output of 57918?

Comment: he is exactly what he is asking for: 

If you list all of the integers greater than 0 and less than 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, you get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these numbers is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 that are less than 500.

in the driver he has this: 

System.out.println("Testing prob1Rec(). Should print 57918:");
System.out.println(PS7.prob1Rec(0, 1));

Comment: I also get 57918.  If you're not getting that, you've done something wrong.

Comment: i added the if statement you said to the code i already had and i dont get that, dont know why

Comment: Wait sorry, instead of using 3 and 5 use 0 and 1. 0 and 1 should give you 57918. i know 3 and 5 does.

Comment: No, 0 and 1 should give you 124750.

Comment: i guess the teacher made a mistake because that is what i get for 0 and 1 as well, thank you for all your help

Comment: More likely, you misunderstood the teacher.  You see, with 0 and 1, you're adding ALL the numbers in the range.  With 3 and 5, you're adding just SOME of them.  Common sense says that the two answers are not going to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `i % num1` performs a division, so your code is not safe.

Add this line as the first line of your method:

```
if (num1 == 0 || num2 == 0)
    return 0;
```

Comment: No.  If one of the numbers is zero, presumably we still want to add up the multiples of the other number.